# form submission in angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router. When form is submitted, I want to activate the ui-routing, which is defined with `ui-sref= "url"` There is no `action` element in Angularjs, so I am using the `ng-submit` element.

How/where do i define the `ui-sref` url ?

The `form` typically has the following code. But the 'url' below is not routed thru the ui-router.

```
form(name="LNquestionForm", action="/url")
```

I want to do something like

```
form(name="LNquestionForm", ng-submit='ui-sref = "url" ')
```

So that the routing takes place thru myAngularApp.js as:-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('/url', {
      url: "/url",
       templateUrl: "partials/someLink" }

    })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not quite sure I get your question right but from what I understood you want to submit a form and be redirected to a given state of your $statePorivider without any server call. If this is the case you could easily do something like that :

```
<form ng-submit="onFormSubmit" name="myForm">
  <input type="text" required/>
  ....
</form>
```

In the controller associated with your form you should do :

```
$scope.onFormSubmit = function () {
  if(myForm.$valid) {
    $state.href('/url' [, optional parameters if needed]);
  }
}
```

Be careful for the onFormSubmit function to work you need to inject the state service in your controller or have it referred in your application Controller.

Please also note that I added some form validation in the example.